# Overriding screen refresh rate

Tags: windows, graphics, overriding, driver, monitor

I am using the EDID override driver to set the screen refresh rate. I am trying to set my DELL 2209WA to 75Hz in 1680x1050. This works but it goes back to default 60Hz when waking up from sleep mode. I assume this has something to do with the ATI graphics card. How can I configure it to stay in 75Hz mode?

Specs:

- Dell 2209WA
- ATI Radeon HD 4550
- Win 7 64-bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstalling ATI Catalyst Control Center solved my problem.